# How to create a rainbow wave on LED Strip using Arduino?

Tags: arduino, rgb, led

I want to create some effects for my led strip with my arduino nano as the controller.

So far I managed to get the basics done (same static color for each led, color fade with each leds simultaneous).
I got a rainbow effect working, but its basically only a cycle through the color spectrum for all leds at the same time.

What I want is a **rainbow wave**, where the colors are moving in one direction and fading into/chasing each other.

Comment: No sorry, i have absolutely no idea. Thats why im asking here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume you want something like this:

[image]

I am using the FastLED library for this, but I think you can change the code a bit to make it work with different LED libraries.

```
#include <FastLED.h>

#define NUM_LEDS 60      /* The amount of pixels/leds you have */
#define DATA_PIN 7       /* The pin your data line is connected to */
#define LED_TYPE WS2812B /* I assume you have WS2812B leds, if not just change it to whatever you have */
#define BRIGHTNESS 255   /* Control the brightness of your leds */
#define SATURATION 255   /* Control the saturation of your leds */

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

void setup() {
  FastLED.addLeds<LED_TYPE, DATA_PIN>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
}

void loop() {
  for (int j = 0; j < 255; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) {
      leds[i] = CHSV(i - (j * 2), SATURATION, BRIGHTNESS); /* The higher the value 4 the less fade there is and vice versa */ 
    }
    FastLED.show();
    delay(25); /* Change this to your hearts desire, the lower the value the faster your colors move (and vice versa) */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

have you tried `fill_rainbow` from `FastLED` library? Not tested but should work.

```
#include "FastLED.h"                                     

#define LED_DT 1                                     

#define COLOR_ORDER GRB                                       
#define LED_TYPE WS2812                                       
#define NUM_LEDS 15                                   
 
uint8_t max_bright = 255;                         
 
struct CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS]; 
 
void setup() {
 
  Serial.begin(115200);
 
  LEDS.addLeds<LED_TYPE, LED_DT, COLOR_ORDER>(leds, NUM_LEDS);      
 
  FastLED.setBrightness(max_bright);         
 
} // setup()
 
 
 
void loop () {
    uint8_t thisSpeed = 10;
    uint8_t deltaHue= 10;
    uint8_t thisHue = beat8(thisSpeed,255); 
    fill_rainbow(leds, NUM_LEDS, thisHue, deltaHue);            
    FastLED.show();
}
```

Comment: deserves way more upvotes, Fastled's fill functions are great.

Answer (score 2):

Same assumption, different approach: you want something like this (love this gif):

[image]

It is working with the latest `FastLED` library 'onboard' features more even timing and smooth  found [here](https://github.com/s-marley/FastLED-basics/blob/main/2.%20Colors%20-%20RGB%20and%20HSV/hsvRainbow/hsvRainbow.ino):

```c++
#include <FastLED.h>

#define NUM_LEDS  18
#define LED_PIN   2

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

//has to be uint8_t so it starts at 0 after it reached 256
uint8_t hue = 0;

void setup() {
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, LED_PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
  FastLED.setBrightness(50);
}

void loop() {
  
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; ++i) {
    leds[i] = CHSV(hue + (i * 10), 255, 255);
  }

  //You can change the pattern speed here
  EVERY_N_MILLISECONDS(15){
    hue++;
  }
  
  FastLED.show();
}
```

Have fun with it :)